# Could there be closed curves in R^3 with tetrahedral symmetry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, symmetry

#### Question

Is there a closed curve in $\mathbb R^3$ that has tetrahedral, octahedral, or icosahedral symmetry?
By *closed curve* I mean a continuously differentiable function $\gamma\colon S^1\to\mathbb R^3$.
By *tetrahedral symmetry* I mean that the symmetry group of the curve contains that of a tetrahedron.
Octahedral and icosahedral symmetries are defined similarly.

#### Motivation

If I want to display a hexagonal prism in a gif animation,
it suffices to rotate the prism by 60 degrees
and the infinitely looping gif will make it look like the prism is rotating forever.

Now I want to display a tetrahedron $T$ (in general, any polyhedron) in a gif animation.
I want to find a way to rotate $T$ so that in the last frame of the gif,
the rotated $T$ looks exactly the same as the $T$ in the first frame
but they actually differ by a nontrivial rotation.

Comment: 1) Do you accept spline curves ? 2) Should your curves be closed or not ? 3) Should they more or less follow the edges of the given polyhedra ?

Comment: (1) Anything C1 is good. I can probably *smoothify* it once an explicit construction is given. (2) Yes, it should be a map from $S^1$ to our world. (3) Not at all.

Comment: http://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/KleinQuartic/KleinQuartic.html

Comment: @JeanMarie Can you elaborate? As it says Klein quartic curves are actually *surfaces*. I don't see how they are closed curves.

Comment: Browse [this](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/klein.html): you will see an animation displaying it as a real 3D curve.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. Are we talking about the skeleton of Klein quadratic or a geodesic of that? I see that the skeleton has tetrahedral symmetry but the skeleton does not form a closed curve/Hamilton cycle, as every vertex is of degree 7 (or 3 if we are talking about the dual). For the geodesics, it is hard to imagine that their images in the 3D world have such symmetry.

Comment: See the graphics below. Besides, I will attempt to obtain a spline solution  for a curve having the isometry group of a cube.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer.** Just a way to insert a graphics.

Have you seen this (animated) curve, the 20th image in the [Baez document](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/klein.html):

[image]

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I can see that there could be some interesting/symmetric Euler/Hamilton cycle on this graph. Although I also want to confess that I know very little about how to construct them even for cases as small as this.

Answer (score 2):

One cheating solution is to take the edges of the tetrahedron, duplicate them, and then take a Eulerian Cycle that goes over every edge twice.

If you require non-self-intersection, then I think the symmetry group needs to be the symmetries of a polygon, so it’s not possible. See https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1982-084-03/S0002-9939-1982-0640242-2/S0002-9939-1982-0640242-2.pdf

Comment: I would like to allow self-intersection. After all, I was asking for the trajectory of a camera. But I also need that the curve is $C^1$, or at least it should not contain any *hard-turn*. Put it in another way, I want the map $\gamma\colon S^1\to\mathbb R^3$ to obey symmetry, not just the image (as a set of points).

Comment: I think your link to  GULLIVER and MORGAN's work answers my question negatively. Still, I wonder if allowing self-intersection would change anything.

Comment: Hmm, if wanted smoothness and the image to obey symmetry, you could smooth out the corners into 3 lines depending on which two edges your transitioning between. Then you can take the dual graph whose vertices are edges and whose edges are adjacent edges and do the same Eulerian path trick. I don’t think having symmetry of the map is possible (but not sure of a proof of that).